# How do I configure Magento 1 to work with Elasticsearch?

Tags: magento-1.9, solr, elasticsearch, centos

I have installed Elasticsearch on my CentOS server, however, there is no tutorial on the web that could explain how to configure it to work with Magento 1. All tutorials available are about M2 only. Any help?